Add variable to SQL series of commands
I have a series of commands I need to run together
DELETE FROM public.table1
WHERE attribute_1 = 'azerty';

DELETE FROM table2
WHERE attribute_2 = 'azerty';

I don't want to specify 'azerty' multiple times, what's the right way to have it in a variable, something like the following:
MyVar = 'azerty';

DELETE FROM public.table1
WHERE attribute_1 = MyVar;

DELETE FROM table2
WHERE attribute_2 = MyVar;


What [tag:rdbms] are you using?
